# Laplace transform of the function $f_\epsilon (x)$

Tags: limits, laplace-transform

Let $f_\epsilon (x)$ be defined as $$f_\epsilon (x)=
\begin{cases}
1/\epsilon,  & 0\leq x\leq \epsilon \\
0, & x> \epsilon
\end{cases}$$

I calculated the laplace transform of $f_\epsilon (x)$ to be $$L(f_\epsilon (x))=\frac{1-e^{-p\epsilon}}{p\epsilon}$$

I want to find the limit of this Laplace transform $\lim_\limits{\epsilon \to 0}L(f_\epsilon(x))$. However I'm not sure how to do this. Any help?

Comment: As $\epsilon$ becomes larger and larger, the numerator comes closer to $1$. On the other hand, the denominator is still getting larger. What can we say about the limit then?

Comment: Isn't it the case that you want to find the limit as $\epsilon\to 0$ instead? I am asking this because this is what is typically done to get the Laplace transform of the delta-function.

Comment: @GReyes Sorry. That was actually a typo.

Comment: Well now you are just taking $-1/p$ times the derivative of $e^{-p\epsilon}$ with respect to $\epsilon$ at $\epsilon=0$. This will turn out to be just $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a Taylor expansion of the exponential $e^{-p\epsilon}=1-p\epsilon+(p\epsilon)^2/2+...$. The $1$ will cancel, and what you are left with is $$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{p\epsilon+(p\epsilon)^2/2+...}{p\epsilon}=1$$

Answer (score 1):

Apply L'Hospital rule   $$\lim _{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{1-e^{-p\epsilon}}{p\epsilon}= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} e^{-p\epsilon} =1$$